# How does one extract data from a 3rd party application/program

Tags: database, extract

How would one go about extracting data from a 3rd party application to use/analyze/act upon?

- Is there a standard practice?
- Is there any good litterature online that you could recommend to
  learn more about this?

**An example:** Say there is some specific data on a website that I want to track in an app or on another website. How would I go about retrieving that data to use or display in my app/on my website? Stockvalue of A or the temperature in B.

**Another example:** Say you are making an AI/bot that can play hearthstone or starcraft. How would you extract information about the game states, e.g. what cards are currently on the table, what cards have my opponent played? etc.

I understand there probably isn't a clear or easy answer, but I have had a hard time finding good litterature/resources on how one does these type of thing. I was hoping someone could give some recommendations.

Comment: Sorry for the poor use of tags, the site wouldn't let me use the appropriate ones due to lack of rep.

Answer (score 1):

**Concerning first example:**
If the website is just a standard HTML website it can by quite easy. You wuold just download the sites XML/HTML representation, store it on your computer and write some code which is able to parse through XML-Data. The HTML representation could look something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    ...some content
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>The Stockvalue is...</p>

        <p>The temperature is...</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The small programm you code would now extract the data between those `<p>`-Tags

**Concerning second example:**
Many games have modsupport. The developers of the game provide some functions which allow you to modify their game. I don't know if this is the case for Starcraft, but there may be a function (provided by developer) that allows you to track game states and write some own code to react to these game states.

Another way of tracking game states could be by making a screenshot of the game. Your AI would then try to find out the current state of the game based on the screenshot (some Minesweeper-Bots use this technique).

Comment: Thank you for the input on example one.

While the info on answer two is useful, it is not quite the answer I sought.